# Alternatives for PL/SQL Group Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I imported a needed old PL/SQL package that uses Group functions such as:

- Get_Group_Char(or Number)_Cell
- Find_Group
- Create_Group
- Add_Group
- Set_Group_Char(or Number)_Cell
- Delete_Group_Row
- Delete_Group

And the ff datatypes:

- RecordGroup
- GroupColumn

However, when I try to compile it errors occur since it seems that these functions/datatypes are undefined/undeclared. I have been told what these functions do and now understand their uses. I am just asking if there are existing packages that implement these functions so that I do not have to code them myself. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean in oracle forms ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I am looking for procedures equivalent of that in oracle forms.

Comment: You do not provide enough info to understand the problem. What means "I imported a needed old PL/SQL package..."?

Comment: It simply means I have a package that uses the procedures/functions above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle Forms built-ins as above cannot be used in PL/SQL. These are to be used in Forms only.